# What is the best way with the newest react native version to include custom icons?

Tags: react-native, icons, font-awesome

**The Question:**

There are many post and articles out there where you can read how to use custom fonts. Most of them seem very complicated and feels "hacky". So with the 2 newest release (0.6 and 0.61) of react-native I thought maybe there is another and better way to do this hidden in the docs.

**So what is the best way to use custom icons?**

Another question:

A friend of mine is my designer for our new app we are developing. And his designs use FontAwesome Pro Icons (which he pays for).

Am I allowed to use it when he downloads it and send it  to me? It's basically our project and I will add both as devs for this project. **Is this allowed?**

If yes I would still prefer to my first question, since when I get it as download it counts as "custom font" that I have to put in a directory somewhere right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [icomoon](https://icomoon.io/) to create an icon font and [react-native-vector-icons](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons) to display them in react native.